# list records with BlockedOn not NULL and numeric value greater than zero or auto-numeric sort in reverse order

Tags: mysql, sorting

Currently, I'm submitting a query and manually sorting fields to see if one field has BlockedOn greater than 0. I know it's very simplistic, but what I would like to do is make this more efficient and eliminate the prompt to "fetch" remaining rows if possible.

**Can we either:**

1. Display only records with BlockedOn greater than zero but not (NULL) or;
2. Sort on the BlockedOn with the initial query so that BlockedOn
   values appear at the top?

No insult intended to the experts by providing excessive information, but this is what I know about BlockedOn:

*BlockedOn  INTEGER     If the current connection is not blocked, this is zero. If it is blocked, the connection number on which the connection is blocked because of a locking conflict.*